# Delete files from command line using smb:// URL

Tags: samba, server-message-block

I have a file with a list of smb:// URLs, like this one:

```
smb://my_samba_host/data/need_to_be_removed.tgz
smb://my_samba_another/data/need_to_be_removed2.tgz
```

I need a command line (something using xargs probably) that would allow me to remove all those files and I'm struggling to come up with one.

Answer (score 7):

Linux or Windows or *whatever*?

Linux: `smbclient … -c "rm $filename"` – but be aware of filenames with unusual characters: you may have to escape or quote `$filename`.

Alternate solution: simply mount the filesystem(s), and access the files with the usual command-line tools.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Matthias Urlichs answer,

`smbclient ... -c "del $filename"`

Per [smbclient documentation](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages/smbclient.1.html).